# Unable to start Call Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, call

I am unable to start the Call activity. I get the following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

This is my code:

```
Intent iCall =new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
iCall.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNum));
startActivityForResult(iCall, Codes.Prefs.CALL_CODE);
```

The funny thing is that this should always work, because the android phone can always make a phone call, regardless of whether an app is installed or not, because making phone calls is built-in. Right?

Thanks!

Comment: have you set permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: put some logs in and show what phone umber has and what the data of the intent is being set to. The next thing to check would be to to post the LOGCAT, we need to see the stacktrace. I'm guessing it could be a permission problem.

Comment: I do already have the Permission in the Manifest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use only one line of code :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:18004581552")));
```

with the permission in manifest file

```
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

Comment: lol...the issue was that I didn't have tel: in front of the phone number...Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: but why down vote for this answer? i have upvoted to remove that.

Comment: down vote?  I'm a bit curious too...lol...I didn't know that I needed tel: in front of the url...

Comment: dnt worry buddy I also get :D

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest file for your application, make sure you have the permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">`

Also, your Intent should look more like this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: lol...the issue was that I didn't have tel: in front of the phone number...Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

did you give the permission in Android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```